# Como fazer Generic com 2 classes em C#

Tags: c#, genéricos

Boa noite,

Estou enfrentando problemas ao usar `Generics` em `C#`, sou programador `Java` e estou aprendendo a usar `C#`.

Quero usar `Generics` em uma classe no pacote `Service`, estou implementando a classe referente ao objeto mapeado, que seria `Plano` e a classe `PlanoDao`.

Classes no pacote Model:

```
namespace Cobranca.pkgModel
{
    public abstract class Persistant
    {
        private long id;
        //getter e setter
    }
}

namespace Cobranca.pkgModel {
    public class Plano : Persistant 
    {
        private string nome;
        private string tipoCobranca;
        private double valor;
        //getter e setter
    }
}
```

Classes no pacote DAO:

```
namespace Cobranca.pkgDao
{
    public abstract class Dao<Model> where Model : Persistant
    {
        //métodos
    }
}

namespace Cobranca.pkgDao
{
    public class PlanoDao : Dao<Plano>
    {
        //metodos;
    }
}
```

Classes no pacote Service:

```
namespace Cobranca.pkgService
{
    public abstract class Service<Model, DAO> where Model : Persistant where DAO : Dao<Persistant>
    {
        //métodos
    }
}




namespace Cobranca.pkgService
{
    public class PlanoService : Service<Plano, PlanoDao<Plano>>
    {
        //metodos
    }
}
```

Estou na dúvida se estou fazendo certo, na classe `PlanoService` me gera erro:

```
Gravidade   Código  Descrição   Projeto Arquivo Linha   Estado de Supressão
Erro    CS0308  O tipo não genérico "PlanoDao" não pode ser usado como argumentos de tipo   Cobranca    C:\Users\Diego\source\repos\Cobranca\Cobranca\pkgService\PlanoService.cs    8   Ativo
```

O que estou fazendo de errado?

Cheguei a declarar na assinatura da classe `PlanoService` assim também:

```
public class PlanoService : Service<Plano, PlanoDao>
```

Mas continua gerando outro erro:

```
Gravidade   Código  Descrição   Projeto Arquivo Linha   Estado de Supressão
Erro    CS0311  O tipo "Cobranca.pkgDao.PlanoDao" não pode ser usado como parâmetro de tipo "DAO" no tipo ou método genérico "Service<Model, DAO>". Não há conversão de referência implícita de "Cobranca.pkgDao.PlanoDao" em "Cobranca.pkgDao.Dao<Cobranca.pkgModel.Persistant>".  Cobranca    C:\Users\Diego\source\repos\Cobranca\Cobranca\pkgService\PlanoService.cs    8   Ativo
```

Quem poderia me salvar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seu tipo genérico na classe abstrata de serviço deve acompanhar o mesmo tipo definido por `Model` e na classe concreta deve especificar uma classe que seja herança de `Dao<Persistant>`.

Uma dica: No C# é comum chamar os tipos genéricos com o "T" no início do nome para não confundir com nomes de classes.

Tente a seguinte assinatura para as classes no pacote `Service`:

```
namespace Cobranca.pkgService
{
    public abstract class Service<Model, DAO> where Model : Persistant where DAO : Dao<Model>
    {
        //métodos
    }
}

namespace Cobranca.pkgService
{
    public class PlanoService : Service<Plano, PlanoDao>
    {
        //metodos
    }
}
```

Comment: Quando você diz usar o prefixo T antes do nome do genérico, seria tipo `Tmodel`, `TDAO` e assim por diante?

Comment: Isso mesmo. Normalmente usa apenas T quando é um tipo. Fica algo como `Service<T>`

Comment: Uma dúvida, no meu caso, se eu quiser implementar um método no `PlanoService`, não terei acesso a ele porque tem que ser implementado no `Service`. Como lidar com isso?

Comment: @Macario1983 crie uma nova pergunta com dados desse outro contexto para que outras pessoas também possam te ajudar.